# Set Block Template In Nested Reference

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, layout-update

So after spending 3 hours on this I am out of ideas. How can I set the template for the block commented below (:32) from my custom layout file. This is the original layout (I'm running Magento 1.9):

```
<layout>
    <review_product_list translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Reviews List</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
                    <action method="disableGallery"/>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml">
                    <!-- workaround: a better place for this code is in paypal.xml -->
                    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="review.product.info.addtocart.paypal.wrapper" translate="label" module="paypal">
                        <label>PayPal Express Checkout Shortcut Wrapper</label>
                        <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="review.product.info.addtocart.paypal" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
                            <action method="setIsInCatalogProduct"><value>1</value></action>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.tierprices" as="tierprices" template="catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/template" name="product.info.other" as="other" template="review/product/view/other.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" />
                <block type="core/template" name="product_review_list.count" template="review/product/view/count.phtml" />
                <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
                    <!-- THIS BLOCK HERE --><block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                            <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                            <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </review_product_list>
```

And this is what I have reached so far but doesnt seem to work:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

     <review_product_list translate="label">


      <reference name="review_form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                  <template>appfactory/review/form.phtml</template>
            </action>
      </reference>
```

## Update 1

Okay so I made some progress and discovered that the problem is not initially in picking up the layout updates, I can't actually change the template of the block. So If i changed it to the following:

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
    <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"  template="appfactory/review/form.phtml">
        <action method="setTemplate">
           <template>appfactory/review/form.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
            <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</block>
```

the block template is still not updated to `appfactory/review/form.phtml` and still picks up the old template `review/form.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with below code:

```
     <reference name="review_form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                  <template>appfactory/review/form.phtml</template>
            </action>
      </reference>
```

Replace with:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <review_product_list translate="label">
        <reference name="product.review.form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>appfactory/review/form.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </review_product_list>
</layout>
```

Comment: This is actually Magento 1.9, don't think I have referenceBlock yet

Comment: Updated answer please check it

Comment: I actually updated the question, the template is not getting picked up even if I set both setTemplate and the template attribute

Comment: add my given code in local.xml of your theme it is working fine for me